# IE11 Paints Much Less Frequently than Firefox or Chrome - How to Get IE to paint more frequently?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, browser

I am using AngularJS 1.5 and aim to create some draggable divs and images.

I have a bunch of absolutely positioned divs and images that have ng-style. There is a directive that listens to a mousedown and subsequent mousemove, and when as the element is dragged, applies a style (for example {left: 20px, top: 100px}) based on the cursor position, updates a model carrying top, left, width and height properties, which ng-style uses. This operates very smoothly on Chrome, a little slower on Firefox, and abysmally slow on IE11. I am trying to get IE11 to perform adequately.

After looking at the performance profiles, it appears that IE is not calling paint on as frequently as Chrome. Chrome processes the one mousemove event in approximately 6ms (see below), and paints roughly every 16ms for 60fps.

For some reason, using the same code, IE11 calculates a bunch of mousemove events without painting the screen, causing FPS to be abysmal. How do I increase the frequency of painting the screen?

**Does anyone have any ideas as to how to increase the painting frequency?**

Chrome Profile:
One mousemove event processed in ~5ms, painting occurs every 16ms.
[image]

IE11 Profile:
One mousemove event processed in ~10ms, but many are called without painting, and painting occurs every 100-200ms, resulting in poor FPS.

[image]